# RHEL7 boot logs show systemd-fsck errors, referencing fsck.ext2, when trying to run on an XFS file system

Tags: fsck

I get these errors when trying to boot CentOS 7:

```
Jul  6 13:20:15 systemd-fsck: fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/disk/by-uuid/45544ef5-118c-478f-a3e8-a4953b3fe71b

Jul  6 13:20:15 systemd-fsck: fsck failed with error code 8.

Jul  6 13:20:15 systemd-fsck: Ignoring error.

Jul  6 13:33:17 systemd-fsck: fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/disk/by-uuid/45544ef5-118c-478f-a3e8-a4953b3fe71b

Jul  6 13:33:17 systemd-fsck: fsck failed with error code 8.

Jul  6 13:33:17 systemd-fsck: Ignoring error.
```

This is a boot partion XFS. I found that it's a [known problem](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/971793) in RHEL 7, but I don't have access to them. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue with LVM. The crux of the matter was that systemd was running its systems-fsck immediately after the initrd switch_root, so the file system had not settled. In the source code systems-fsck queries udev for the filesystem type, and if this is run too quickly after switch_root, udev returns NULL. A very simple solution was to add one line to the service, to pause for 3 seconds, before running the fsck. This is a diff:

```
root@localhost:/usr/lib/systemd/system$ diff -u systemd-fsck-root.service.orig systemd-fsck-root.service
--- systemd-fsck-root.service.orig  2015-11-24 23:15:22.593388104 +0000
+++ systemd-fsck-root.service   2015-11-24 21:52:13.489345153 +0000
@@ -17,6 +17,7 @@
 [Service]
 Type=oneshot
 RemainAfterExit=yes
+ExecStart=/bin/sleep 3
 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-fsck
 StandardOutput=journal+console
 FsckPassNo=1
```